# Formstone upload maxQueue not working

Tags: jquery, upload, limit, progress

I am using this plugin jquery https://formstone.it/components/upload/ and everything works perfect, but ... has an option to limit the maximum file up and does not work, called "maxQueue".

My code is this:

```
var $filequeue,
    $filelist;

    $filequeue = $(".filelist.queue");
    $filelist = $(".filelist.complete");

    $(".upload").upload({
        label: "SUELTA AQUI",
        maxQueue: 1,
    }).on("start.upload", onStart)
      .on("complete.upload", onComplete)
      .on("filestart.upload", onFileStart)
      .on("fileprogress.upload", onFileProgress)
      .on("filecomplete.upload", onFileComplete)
      .on("fileerror.upload", onFileError);

function onStart(e, files) {
    console.log("Start");
    var html = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        html += '<li data-index="' + files[i].index + '"><span class="file">' + files[i].name + '</span><span class="progress">Cola</span></li>';
    }
    $filequeue.append(html);
}

function onComplete(e) {
    console.log("Complete");
    // All done!
}

function onFileStart(e, file) {
    console.log("File Start");
    $filequeue.find("li[data-index=" + file.index + "]")
              .find(".progress").text("0%");
}

function onFileProgress(e, file, percent) {
    console.log("File Progress");
    $filequeue.find("li[data-index=" + file.index + "]")
              .find(".progress").text(percent + "%");
}

function onFileComplete(e, file, response) {
    console.log("File Complete");
    if (response.trim() === "" || response.toLowerCase().indexOf("error") > -1) {
        $filequeue.find("li[data-index=" + file.index + "]").addClass("errorb")
                  .find(".progress").text(response.trim());
    } else {
        var $target = $filequeue.find("li[data-index=" + file.index + "]");
        $target.find(".file").text(file.name);
        $target.find(".progress").remove();
        $target.appendTo($filelist);
        console.log(response);
    }
}

function onFileError(e, file, error) {
    console.log("File Error");
    $filequeue.find("li[data-index=" + file.index + "]").addClass("errorb")
              .find(".progress").text("Error: " + error);
}

                            <div class="upload target" data-upload-options='{"action":"<?php echo get_template_directory_uri().'/inc/upload.php'; ?>", "maxSize": "1048576", "maxQueue": "1"}'></div>
```

Everything works perfect, but there is no limit, lets you upload 1, 10, 100 or all you want.

What can be wrong?

Comment: maybe there shouldn't be a comma after it

Answer (score 0):

The maxQueue parameter determines how many files should be uploaded in parallel, not the total number of files that can be uploaded altogether. You'll notice with maxQueue set to 1, only a single upload occurs at the same time. The plugin will wait for the first to finish before starting the next transfer.